# A question on Periodic Sturm Liouville Problem (SLP)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $$[p(x)y']'+[\lambda q(x)+r(x)]y=0$$ on $[a,b]$ $y(a)=y(b)$ and $y'(a)=y'(b)$ where $p(a)=p(b)$ and $p'(x), q'(x), r(x)$ are continuous and $p(x)>0, q(x)>0$ on $a\leq x\leq b$ then Let $V=E_{\lambda_{1}}\oplus E_{\lambda_{2}}\oplus+\dots$ where $E_{\lambda_{i}}$ are eigen space corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ then

$(a)$ dim $E_{\lambda_{i}}\leq 2$

$(b)$ dim V is countably infinite

$(c)$ dim $E_{\lambda_{i}}=2$ for all except one value of $\lambda_i$

$(d)$ dim ($E_{\lambda_{i}}\cap E_{\lambda_{j}})=0$ for $i\neq j$

Efforts:

This is a periodic Sturm Livouille problem. Eigenvalues of SLP are countable in numbers so option $2$ is correct.

How should I approach the rest of the options?